# Proving a statement using the information about function's derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Function $u(x,y)$ is called a harmonic function if it has partial derivatives from the first degree ($f'_x , f'_y)$ and second degree ($f''_{xx}, f''_{xy}, f''_{yx}, f''_{yy}$) that are continuous, and for every $(x,y)$ this equation holds: 
> $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2} =0$
>
> Prove: if $u(x,y)$ is a harmonic function and $f(u)\in C^2, (u\ne Constant)$ (I'm not sure of the notation but from the question I can understand it means that partial derivatives are continuous up to second degree), and the function $z(x,y)=f(u(x,y))$ is harmonic function, then $f(u)=Au + B$.

Before adding my work and attempt, I have to say I haven't really understood what $A,B$ are in what I needed to prove, I don't know if it's a mistake in the question or just me not understanding, but I decided to look at them as constants because it's the only thing I thought of that they could be. 

**My attempt**:
All what I have tried is to take derivatives and find conclusions and try to use the information that I got about harmonifc functions: 
**Updated**

$z_x=f'(u)u_x$ 
$z_y=f'(u)u_y$
$z_{xx}=f''(u)u_x^2 + f'(u)u_{xx}$ 
$z_{yy}=f''(u)u_y^2 + f'(u)u_{yy}$ 
Now given that $z$ is harmonic: $z_{xx}+z_{yy} = 0$
$f''(u)u_x^2 + f'(u)u_{xx} + f''(u)u_y^2 + f'(u)u_{yy}=f'(u)[u_{xx}+u_{yy}]+f''(u)[u_{x}^2+u_y^2]$
And since $u$ is harmonic we get $=f''(u)[u_x^2+u_y^2]=0$

I'm not sure how to continue since I can't see any problem in $f''(u)=0$ or $u_x^2+u_y^2=0$. BUT I know one thing, if I get that $f''(u)=0$ that means $f'(u)=c$ where $c$ is a constant, which means $f(u)=Au + B$.
**Update 2** 
if $u_x^2 + u_y^2 = 0$ , then $ u_x=0 and u_y=0$, and that means $u=Const$, which contradicts the information that $u\ne Const$.

The idea / approach I have in my mind is to find $f'(u)=A$ (some constant), and then I will have that $f(u)=Au+B$.

Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are writing is incorrect notation. $f'(u(x,y))$ is very different from differentiating $f(u(x,y))$. And what does $^\prime$ mean? You should be writing $z_x$ and $z_y$, then computing $z_{xx}+z_{yy}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry about the $'$ it's the notation my professor used for partial derivatives and he said $f'_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ so I thought it's used like that, but $f'(u(x,y))$ is probably my own mistake I'm still weak in derivatives and trying my best, What I did was $f'(u)$, and since $u(x,y)$ I did write $f'(u(x,y))$, I'm not getting why it's wrong, it's a function that has one variable that is a two variable function, so when I'm differentiating by $u$ that means I need to differentiate $u$ by $x$ and $y$ or atleast thats what I thought, would love to hear corrections

Comment: No, $f'(u(x,y))$ means simply that we calculate $f'(u)$ and substitute $u=u(x,y)$. This has nothing to do with differentiating the composite function $z=f(u(x,y))$. For example, $z_x = f'(u(x,y))u_x$ and $z_y=f'(u(x,y))u_y$. Now differentiate again, both the product rule and the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks alot for the explanation, I've updated my attempt following your corrections, Edit: Updated again now after reaching the answer, thanks alot, would appreciate an approval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well done. So you have it now. Since $u$ is nonconstant, we know that $u_x^2+u_y^2$ cannot be everywhere $0$ (indeed, because $u$ is harmonic, we know that it can be $0$ only at isolated points). Therefore, $f''(u)=0$. No you're back to single-variable calculus — assuming the domain of $f$ is an interval, $f'(u)=A$ is constant, and so $f(u)=Au+B$ for some constant $B$.